# No way to exclude method from being exposed by JAX-WS as web service operation

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I'm creating a web service in Java EE 6 annotating an enterprise bean with `@WebService`.
I need to expose only some of the bean methods, so I've annotated with `@WebMethod` only the required ones.
Unfortunately JAX-WS ignores the annotations and try to expose all methods. The trouble is that there is one method, that's not intended to be used as a web service operation, that returns an interface and this cannot be managed by JAX-WS, so the web service is not deployed.
Is this an expected behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: You can set the visibility of the method to protected ( or language equivalent ) JAX-WS exposes all public methods by default ( which I thoroughly agree with).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could add the attribute 'exclude' to the annotation and set it to true. The Javadoc states: Marks a method to NOT be exposed as a web method.

Comment: I just had to press ctrl+space to get annotation parameters and the solution was there! Thanks a lot.

Comment: but this is not possible in CXF, it throws exception - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3128?focusedCommentId=12932648&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12932648